# Is heating load related to volume of area/surface?

Tags: hvac, heating, heat-pump

I am working to improve distribution of my heating (ductwork). I found multiple sources to calculate the heating load (either per room or whole house):

1. Most of them use the volume (room area times ceiling height) with some factor ([Example 1](https://www.plumbersstock.com/how-to-hvac/calculate-heat-load.html), [Example 2](https://www.calculator.net/btu-calculator.html), [Example 3](https://www.servicetitan.com/tools/hvac-load-calculator))
2. Another one is Sum(U x Area*
   x DeltaT), See [How to do heat load calculations for distribution with common return and/or open floor concept](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274744/how-to-do-heat-load-calculations-for-distribution-with-common-return-and-or-open/274750)

I am confused by the latter: Does it assume a CLOSED surface? If yes, it works out because with R=0, heat load would go to infinity.

But then, isn’t it tiny cracks (eg around the door or even electrical boxes) where cold wold creep in much more easily? Accounting for these is hard, how does one model it? With that simple approximation, any tiny crack with R=0 results in an infinite load.

Lastly how are the two options equivalent based on first principles? The first one only depends on volume, the latter only on area. How does that work out?

Comment: What is your home improvement question?

Comment: @JACK Because I am working on my ductwork (=DIY home improvement) and this is one item that needs to be understood. It's actually a followup question from the linked one.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer to the linked question, the air leakage or ventilation can be measured (via a blower door test) or fudge-factored. So many cubic feet per hour, turn that into pounds of air, multiply by the specific heat of air. The "common 'simple' methods" are just humongous fudge factoring - making broad assumptions that may or may not reflect the actual construction of any particular house, and may or may not predict the heat load at all accurately as a result. See also here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/94978/18078

Answer (score 2):

1 is equivalent to 2 as the "some factor" includes the U values etc

2 is based on the u value of each wall surface and it is those surfaces that loose the heat.

Some of us when  we designed our dwellings also considered the floor and roof and fitted 30cm of insulation. We looked at the degree days and designed to include the passive solar gain form the windows based on the season. The summer was considered so that windows had shading while the winter allowed any sun to enter via the window.

Comment: In terms of equivalency: Method2 is the more “accurate” (direct) one? When you say the factor includes U values etc I still don’t see how we get from volume to area. One is linear in volume, the other linear in area. Or is there an implicit assumption of a cube so that each of the 6 edges (4 walls, 1 floor, 1 ceiling) is (Volume)^(2/3) … and the factor is the average value of the U-values between walls/floors/ceiling/windows of a typical home in that area?