Cooling the garage in the summer: what do you think of my air conditioning plan?
I am leaning towards buying a 12000 BTU portable air conditioner for around $300, and paying a handyman to install a vent in my garage for $300.
That should end up at $600 for an adequate system for cooling my garage.
I've considered the idea of a mini split, but it seems far more expensive and doesn't seem necessary. What are the advantages of a mini split over my tentative plan?
And do portable air conditioners need to drain water in addition to venting the hot air?

The main benefit of minis is they use less power.  Garages make me think of a building with poor or no insulation(from the heat or cold), causing much higher AC/heating costs.

How large is the garage, to what degree is it filled with open space (air) vs storage of vehicles, tools, and other dense heat-retaining objects, and will it be conditioned 24x7 or only a few hours here and there when occupied?

Yes, portables produce condensation that has to be removed.

Is there a reason you want to use a portable unit (with hoses to the outside) instead of a window or thru-the-wall AC?

Whether 12,00 BTU would be adequate depends on a number of factors, e.g., climate, garage size, and thermal insulation in the garage. See https://inspectapedia.com/heat/Heating-Cooling-Climate-Zone-BTU-Requirements.php, for example for sizing an air conditioner.

"What are the advantages of x vs y?" is a perfectly acceptable question, and one which we steer people toward as opposed to "what should I buy". This shouldn't be closed!

What is the size of the garage (all 3 dimensions) and what is the installed insulation R-Value? 12K is either totally inadequate, adequate, or overkill depending on the installed insulation, area of uninsulated or poorly insulated openings, and temperature differential you are attempting to maintain.

This answer is related, though the question is not a duplicate. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/94978/18078

There are several factors.

Will you want heat?
How much will be using the place/running the A/C or heat?
How much suffering do you wish on the person who pays the electric bill?

Do you want efficiency?
First, portable air conditioners are absolutely horrible products because of their low efficiency. Something that has bit more than one person when they find they can't run much else on that circuit because their lousy portable is sucking all the juice.
You're talking about having someone install a garage vent, so you know about 1-hose portables' tendency to throw away the air they already conditioned and suck more hot wet air into the building.
That's a big deal because humidity is even harder to remove from air than heat!  Much of your total A/C load is wringing humidity out of the air.  It takes 1000 BTU to condense a pound (pint) of water out of air, so if your 5000 BTU/hr unit is pulling 3 pints an hour of water out of the air, that cost 3000 BTU/hr to remove and that's why the thing barely cools.
By eliminating the "suck", 2-hose portables are a step in the right direction because of their much higher efficiency.  (and just to make things more confusing, some 2-hose units use a concentric hose, so it visually appears like one hose.)
Window units are another step up for efficiency, right off the top because they run continuously and don't stop to make you empty the condensate tank. And important to your cheapness, window units are cheaper for the same BTU/hr than the cheapest 1-hose units, even though their real-world BTUs are much better since they're not "sucking".
Top of the pops are mini-splits, some of which have absolutely bonkers 24+ SEER, and also have variable speed drives, so once they reach "cruising altitude" and are simply in maintenance mode, they take even less power.  That's a big deal if you need other loads on that circuit.
Do you need heat?
A space heater makes heat by buying electricity.  1000 watts of electricity gets you 1000 watts of heat (3400 BTU/hr).  But you notice many air conditioners, especially window units or mini-splits, do better than that.  Even a super garbage 1-hose portable may advertise 6800 BTU/hr on 1000 watts. (COP of 2 or SEER of 6.8), and that's terrible - 2-hose, windows, traditional built-in and mini-splits do increasingly better than that!
So how can they be more than 100% efficient?  Because they're not making the heat, they're just pumping the heat that already exists.
So can that work in reverse, and put the heat into your space at efficiencies like 400%?  Oh, you betcha! And we're getting pretty good at it. If a unit is running 2.7 COP, it's bringing in 2700 watts of heat for 1000 watts of load - and that video discusses how that's possible in Chicago all year, becoming less efficient than 2.7x only a few nighttime hours (106) in one of the worst winters on record.  And on those dread cold nights, you're probably not tinkering in the garage anyway.
All air conditioners are heat pumps.  Some just didn't bother to design in some very inexpensive kit that allows them to reverse-cycle and make heat in the cold.
How much do you use it?
Because this is the real question. If you're going to be running the A/C all summer, then SEER/COP really matters. If you're going to be running an electric space heater all winter, then the advantage of a heat pump could pay for the heat pump in less electricity use.  That's where you need to break out some brain cells and work out the numbers.


It isn't clear if 12,000 Btu is enough to cool your garage.  Many garages are un-insulated, and different places have different requirements.  The big uninsulated door is typically a problem, but there are videos on adding insulation to them.

The cheapest portable AC units all have the same problem - they only exhaust air.  That means that all the air they exhaust must be replaced with outside air, which then has to be cooled again.  This can work, but it is inefficient, and will add to your heating load.  There are units with 2 air ducts, these bring in outside air to cool the condenser and are thus more efficient.  The condensate water is typically blown out via the exhaust hose, mine didn't even have a reservoir to empty.

For an installation you want to remain in place, a window unit is probably a better option, unless you are limited by HOA restrictions.  Cutting a larger rectangular hole in the wall versus two smaller holes is probably a wash.  This way you aren't paying for the portability of the portable unit.

Mini-splits will be more to buy and much more to install.  The advantage is the variable-speed compressors most of them have.  That means they run cheaply when the load is less than full, they throttle output instead of running full-bore for less time.  I doubt this would ever pay for itself for a single room of cooling.



...mini-splits are generally, in my experience, a lot quieter than window units, which can be worth paying a bit more for along with the energy savings.
